# Sending a notification when an email is received in Exchange 2007

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

One of our departments is requesting to receive a notification whenever an email is sent to a particular inbox.  So every time an email is sent to mailbox@mycompany.com, they want an email sent to a distribution list saying "A message has arrived."

Is this possible in Exchange 2007 using a Powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a transport rule

```
$condition = Get-TransportRulePredicate From
$condition.addresses = 'someone@contoso.com'
$action = Get-TransportRuleAction CopyTo
$action.addresses = 'otherperson@contoso.com'
New-TransportRule -Name "Notify New Message Recieved" -Conditions $condition -Actions $action
```

Comment: You can change the rule action to whatever you want

use Get-TransportRuleAction to get a list of actions you have on your server

Get-TransportRuleAction <actionname> | fl showed me that modifying .addresses would set the address of the copied email. You can also do the same thing with Get-TransportRulePredicate

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like this is just a matter of creating a rule in Exchange.

Running through the "Rules Wizard":

- Check messages when they arrive
- through the specified account (select account associated with mailbox@mycompany.com)
- run a script (something that will send out the new "A message has arrived." email)
- **OR** forward/redirect it to people or distribution list

Comment: If only a notification is needed (not the whole email) use the "Have Server Reply with Specific Message" rule. I've used it successfully to receive notifications in another mailbox.